# Wpf Control to display htmlcode

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, wpf

I am using a Hit on server and getting the content in `Streamer`.
            I then use a string where I get the Html code of the website.
            I have to use this in a WPF application.
           Which control should I use where I can put a url which contains html code to display in my wpf and HOW??

```
        string urlcode;
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        StreamReader streamr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        urlcode = streamr.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embed the WebBrowser control on the preview tab and pass the HTML into it using the NavigateToString or NavigateToStream methods.

Comment: No news here. Why do you answer exactly what others have answered before?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491073) control and its [NavigateToStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostream) method:

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="webBrower"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com");
webBrower.NavigateToStream(request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
```

This is a simplified example. You would at least have to close/dispose the response object when navigation has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NavigationWindow` to contain the page. You can then call the `Navigate(Uri)` method to traverse from page to page.

[MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationwindow.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can use web browser control ,pass  string containg HTML control to its NavigateToString method

```
  webB.NavigateToString(@"<html>HTML code go here </html>");
```